# Multiple websites with 1 IP and 1 domain name

Tags: server, debian, apache2

My question is rather simple but with my level in sys admin I can't find the answer, I have a playground server with one IP and what I'm trying to do it's to configure multiple site whithout buying another ip or domain name. 
What I want (let's say my ip is 192.168.0.1):
192.168.0.1/ redirects me to some index I configured
192.168.0.1/site1/ redirects me to the index site 1
192.168.0.1/site2/ redirects me to the index site 2
... 
I know about Virtual hosting, I know to config different websites with different IPs and domains names...but I don't know how to configure it in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for a personal use, you can play with your client's host file and VirtualHost.